# Function not returning the correct amount of observations

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a function to show the `n` number of movies most rated by a user in a given dataframe. I have been able to extract the movies the user provided rating for but I cannot return the correct amount of rows - instead it prints all the movies with rating from the user.

I have tried this way as shown in the code with `.head(n_rows)` but it does not work:

```py
def top_movies(data_,usr,n_rows = 10):
    user = data_[data_['user_id']== usr]
    movies = data_.loc[user.index].groupby('title')['title','rating']
    final = movies.head(n_rows).sort_values(by = 'rating' ,ascending = False)
    return final
def ex9():
    return top_movies(data,1,30)
ex9()
```

I expect to print the first 30 rows for example here.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the structure of your dataframe?

Comment: user is a mask, could you try this : movies = data_.loc[user].groupby('title')['title','rating']. movies.sort_values(by = 'rating' ,ascending = False).head(n_rows). And also, doesn't work is not help full at all, please provide the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly, you want to achieve, but check this:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
         'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ],
         'title': ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't1', 't5'],
         'rating': [25, 25, 35, 25, 30,],
        })


df.sort_values(by='rating', ascending=False).groupby('user_id')[['user_id', 'title','rating', ]].nth(list(range(30)))
```